# WebLogic 12c and DataSource

Tags: database, oracle, weblogic, datasource

I can't configure datasource in weblogic and get error

```
Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

But db's and listener is startup and I can connect to db from SQLDeveloper and from simple java code with jdbc. I install Oracle DB client to server and add this to "PATH", but it don't work.

in listener log

```
    11-ДЕК-2014 17:37:33 * service_update * rtu1 * 0
11-ДЕК-2014 17:38:20 * service_update * nsi * 0
11-ДЕК-2014 17:38:48 * service_update * rtuwh1 * 0
11-ДЕК-2014 17:39:53 * service_update * nsi * 0
11-ДЕК-2014 17:40:23 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=RTUARCH)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=fedorov))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.15.15)(PORT=1245)) * establish * RTUARCH * 0
11-ДЕК-2014 17:40:23 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=RTU1)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=fedorov))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.15.15)(PORT=1246)) * establish * RTU1 * 0
11-ДЕК-2014 17:40:23 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=RTU1)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=fedorov))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.15.15)(PORT=1247)) * establish * RTU1 * 0
11-ДЕК-2014 17:40:23 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=RTU1)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=fedorov))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.15.15)(PORT=1248)) * establish * RTU1 * 0
11-ДЕК-2014 17:40:23 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=RTUHW1)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=fedorov))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.15.15)(PORT=1249)) * establish * RTUHW1 * 12505
TNS-12505
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post what your connection string URL looks like inside the weblogic admin console `JDBC Data Sources -> name -> Connection Pool -> URL`?

Comment: Thanks for answer, I resolve my problem (one of many datasources have incorrect db name).

Answer (score 0):

As seen your error log, there is problem with your datasource. Double check your datasource. Also there is option of testing a datasource under monitoring tab.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

It must give you success result.